# How to find different genre then add to arrayed linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to get genres from a file of movies and then check to see if genre is the same. so if in the file there are movies with the same genre they should be stored in the same array of linklist.

i need **check**  the genre's hashcode and then find out if any other movie in the file hash the **same hashcode for genre** then place that particular genre in a linked list. so basically I have this so far and i also have a link list class etc and not using java.util

```
public class LoadingMovies {

    private static final int size = 22;
    private static HashMap<String, Movies> hash = new HashMap(size);
    private static HashEntry<String, Movies> hasher = new HashEntry();
    private static List<Movies> linked = new List<>();

    public static void loadMovies(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String split = ","; //split with comma

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        String wordIn;
        Movies movie = new Movies();

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            wordIn = in.nextLine();
            String splitter[] = wordIn.split(split);

            String movieTitle = splitter[0];
            String movieGenre = splitter[1];
            String ageRating = splitter[2];
            double scoreRating = Double.parseDouble(splitter[3]);

            movie.setTitle(movieTitle);
            movie.setGenre(movieGenre);
            movie.setAgeRating(ageRating);
            movie.setScoreRating(scoreRating);
            //System.out.println(movie.getGenre());
              arraylist.add(movie.getGenre);
//            hash.find(movie.getGenre().hashCode());
//            hash.insert(movie.getGenre().hashCode(), movie);
        }



      }
}
```

This is what i have so far. I already read in the file now I want to check to see if a genre (String) in the file is same and then add that genre to link list. how can I do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what your expected output is? A map from a genre to a list of movies from it?

Comment: @Mureinik yes. so if i search for a particular genre or want to check for most repeated genre it would go to the location that holds more. so my output should be: eg hash entrykey will be the same if the genre is the same and then print out the movies

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap<String, List<Movie>>` seems to be what you're looking for:

```
Map<String, List<Movie>> movieGenres = new HashMap<>();
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    // code you have

    List<Movie> moviesInThisGenre = moviewGenres.get(genre);
    if (moviesInThisGenre == null) {
        moviesInThisGenre = new LinkedList<>();
        movieGenres.put(genre, moviesInThisGenre);
    }
    moviesInThisGenre.add(movie);
}
```

Comment: i get this output when  i run it:'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at TheMoviePackage.HashMap.find(HashMap.java:52)
 at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.loadMovies(LoadingMovies.java:50)
 at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.main(LoadingMovies.java:87)
Java Result: 1'

Comment: this is how i changed it. `movie.setTitle(movieTitle);
            movie.setGenre(movieGenre);
            movie.setAgeRating(ageRating);
            movie.setScoreRating(scoreRating);

            List<Movies> moviesInThisGenre = movieGenres.find(movieGenre);
            if (moviesInThisGenre == null) {
                moviesInThisGenre = new List<>();
                movieGenres.insert(movieGenre, moviesInThisGenre);
            }
            ListIterator<Movies> iter = moviesInThisGenre.getIterator();
            moviesInThisGenre.add(iter, movie);`

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Map that maps from genre String to Lists of Movies:

```
HashMap<String, List<Movies>> genres = new Hash...
```

then when you add a Movie:

```
String g = movie.getGenre();
if (!genres.containsKey(g)
    genres.put(g, new ArrayList<Movies>));
genres.get(g).add(movie);
```

**Explanation**
A HashMap stores values for key objects, where each key object can only occur once in the map. Thus, when you want to store multiple movies for one genre String, the value type should be a collection (List, Set, etc.).
e.g.

```
HashMap<String, Movies> genres ... ;
...
genres.put(g, movie);
```

will override any Movie value you had for that genre before.

But, since you cannot know at runtime if the genre already exists in your Map, you have to put a new (empty) list for an unknown genre. Any movies with that genre can now be added to that list.

Comment: can u please explain.i dont understand hashmaps etc properly yet and just trying. just started learning it .

Comment: Added some explanation, for more, there is plenty out there, e.g.: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/

Comment: -im still getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at TheMoviePackage.HashMap.find(HashMap.java:52)
 at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.loadMovies(LoadingMovies.java:50)
 at TheMoviePackage.LoadingMovies.main(LoadingMovies.java:66)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: it pointing to my find key method which is this                                              `public DataType find(KeyType key){
        int hash = key.hashCode() % size;
        List<HashEntry<KeyType,DataType>> list = table[hash];
        ListIterator <HashEntry<KeyType, DataType>> iter = list.getIterator();
        
        while(iter.isValid()){
            if(iter.item().getKey().equals(key)){
                return iter.item().getData();
            }
            iter.advance();
        }
        return null;
    }
      `  something wrong with it?